# installing 9_Recommended patchcluster to solaris 9

Tags: solaris

i am planning to install 9_Recommended patchcluster.

any recomendation before doing that ?

i placed patches to /var/spool/patch directory , i will launch installer from there

which files should i backup ?

also some patches say use boot -r after install some of them just boot

so boot -r is ok for all after all cluster completed ?

Answer (score 1):

you can install the patch cluster from any directory, i would recommend dropping the machine down to single user mode and then running the patch cluster on the machine, also I have seen sometimes issues with /var filling up if you have this setup on a seperate slice (partition/disk) i would recommending performing some house keeping here to make sure you have a couple of gb free space here.

So you would do something like

1. Reboot into single user mode.
2. run the patches.
3. reboot system again.

Also i would strongly recommend to read the README file to check whether there are any patches which may mean you have to run the cluster patch more than once for all of them to be applied

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a production server, you should already have regular full and incremental backups in place. Installing patches doesn't require specific backups beyond that.

"boot -r" is fine even for packages that do not ask for that option.